# High-dimensional array multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, math, multidimensional-array

Consider the following code.

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.random.random((3,3,3))
array2 = np.random.random((3,3,3))
array3 = array1@array2
```

What does `array3` contain? I know it also has shape `(3,3,3)`. If `array1` and `array2` were two-dimensional, then `array3` would be the matrix multiplication of the arrays. Has the `@` operation a mathematical meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in [PEP 465](https://peps.python.org/pep-0465/):

> For inputs with more than 2 dimensions, we treat the last two
> dimensions as being the dimensions of the matrices to multiply, and
> ‘broadcast’ across the other dimensions. This provides a convenient
> way to quickly compute many matrix products in a single operation. For
> example, `arr(10, 2, 3) @ arr(10, 3, 4)` performs 10 separate matrix
> multiplies, each of which multiplies a 2x3 and a 3x4 matrix to produce
> a 2x4 matrix, and then returns the 10 resulting matrices together in
> an array with shape (10, 2, 4).

So for your code `array3[0, :, :]` contains the result of the matrix-matrix multiplication `array1[0, :, :] @ array2[0, :, :]`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In numpy `@` does [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#:%7E:text=For%20matrix%20multiplication%2C%20the%20number,B%20is%20denoted%20as%20AB.)

While `*` does element wise multiplication or [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices))

Comment: But that wiki article doesn't address how numpy handles 3d arrays. You need to reference `np.matmul`